# Cluster Manager for Message Passing Interface

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, mpj-express

Are there any cluster manager or cluster management system for Message Passing Interface?

I'm planning to use MPJ Express. From the list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_manager, which one can we use for MPI?

thanks

Comment: MPI is a standard for message passing in distributed memory systems. It is completely ambivalent to the kind of distributed resource manager (DRM) that controls the cluster. That said, many popular MPI implementations come with integration support for many popular DRMs like Torque, SGE, SLURM, LFS, etc. In any case, your question is off-topic here as it doesn't directly relate to programming.

Comment: We have released MPJ Express v0.44 , it supports YARN resource manager, hence you can execute your programs on Hadoop clusters.